# Python3/vlc: how to get media stats (function get_stats)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to call the `get_stats()` function on a media:

```
>>> instance = vlc.Instance()
>>> media = instance.media_new('song.mp3')
>>> media.get_stats()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: get_stats() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p_stats'
>>> media.get_stats('input_bitrate')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alain/Audio/vlc.py", line 2517, in get_stats
    return libvlc_media_get_stats(self, p_stats)
  File "/home/alain/Audio/vlc.py", line 5349, in libvlc_media_get_stats
    return f(p_md, p_stats)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_MediaStats instance instead of str
```

The expected argument type `LP_MediaStats` does not exist in `vlc.py`, but I found this:

```
class MediaStats(_Cstruct):
    _fields_ = [
        ('read_bytes',          ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('input_bitrate',       ctypes.c_float),
        ('demux_read_bytes',    ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('demux_bitrate',       ctypes.c_float),
        ('demux_corrupted',     ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('demux_discontinuity', ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('decoded_video',       ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('decoded_audio',       ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('displayed_pictures',  ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('lost_pictures',       ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('played_abuffers',     ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('lost_abuffers',       ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('sent_packets',        ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('sent_bytes',          ctypes.c_int  ),
        ('send_bitrate',        ctypes.c_float),
    ]
```

Do anyone know how to use this function?

Comment: `stats = vlc.MediaStats()` then `print self.Media.get_stats(stats)` but as noted this just returns True or False. It appears to be another work in progress, putting it back after it stopped working. See https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/14035

Comment: Instead of printing with `print self.Media.set_stats(stats)`, just run that call dumping the return value, and then `print stats` - it should have been populated with the stats you are seeking. You may need to parse it using str(stats) and split lines, then in each line there's a tab to separate label from value, so you could read that into a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with documentation [here](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/generated.vlc-module.html#libvlc_media_get_stats). It says:

> `libvlc_media_get_stats(p_md, p_stats)` Get the current statistics
>   about the media.
>
> Parameters:
>   p_md - : media descriptor object.
>   p_stats - : structure
>   that contain the statistics about the media (this structure must be
>   allocated by the caller). Returns: true if the statistics are
>   available, false otherwise \libvlc_return_bool.

According to docs, you should use `media descriptor` as a parameter. Now we have to figure out how to get media descriptor.

Comment: Hmm, I misunderstood what `get_media` is for: I don't want get a boolean, but the stats themselves. So I accept your answer and open a new question.

Comment: https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=examples;hb=HEAD